# jooq 3.7.2 for Java6 doesn't exclude if schema is used

Tags: java, jooq

I'm unable to get 'excludes' to work with licensed jooq 3.7.2 (java 6) connecting to db2. Tried the case insensitive version also. What am I missing? I simply want to ignore an alias in schema myschema pointing to some other table in otherschema. I get a warning 'Ambiguous type name : The object X generates a type #fully qualified class name# which conflicts with the existing type #fully qualified class name#'. Did anybody experience this issue before?

```
<generator>
                            <name>org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator</name>
                            <database>
                                <name>org.jooq.util.db2.DB2Database</name>
                                <includes>.*</includes>
                                <excludes>myschema\.alias</excludes>
                                <schemata>
                                    <schema>
                                        <inputSchema>myschema</inputSchema>
                                        <outputSchema>dest</outputSchema>
                                        <outputSchemaToDefault>true</outputSchemaToDefault>
                                    </schema>
                                    <schema>
                                        <inputSchema>otherschema</inputSchema>
                                        <outputSchema>dest</outputSchema>
                                        <outputSchemaToDefault>true</outputSchemaToDefault>
                                    </schema>
                                </schemata>
                            </database>
                            <target>
                                <packageName>org.comp.model</packageName>
                                <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
                            </target>
                        </generator>
```

Comment: I've explained the warning in my answer. But you said "excludes" is not working for you. Could you perhaps show a bit more information? Is `myschema.alias` an alias as in `CREATE ALIAS ...`?

Comment: Schema A -- has --> Table1, Table2 & Schema B --has --> Table3, A1 (alias to Schema A.Table1). We are trying to do code-generation-time schema mapping redirecting (as you pointed out) both schema's to same target schema. jooq was issuing warnings about ambiguity which is understandable. The ambiguity is because jooq is considering schemaB.A1 and schemaA.Table1 when we do the schemata mapping and both point to "same object".  So to avoid that we tried to supress jooq from considering the Alias using regular expression schemaA\.A1 under excludes but ambiguity still happens.Just A1 omits totally.

Comment: How to make jooq ignore the alias?

Comment: Thank you for these details. I currently don't see an easy way to prevent these aliases from interfering with your code generation. I've registered an issue for formal alias support in jOOQ (https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5564). As a workaround, you could extend the `DB2Database` and hook into the table definition logic, or you could use an `XMLDatabase` as documented here: http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-xml

Answer (score 0):

The warning you're getting probably doesn't really have anything to do with the `excludes` tag you've specified. The warning source is here:

```xml
<schema>
    <inputSchema>myschema</inputSchema>
    <outputSchema>dest</outputSchema>
    <outputSchemaToDefault>true</outputSchemaToDefault>
</schema>
<schema>
    <inputSchema>otherschema</inputSchema>
    <outputSchema>dest</outputSchema>
    <outputSchemaToDefault>true</outputSchemaToDefault>
</schema>
```

You're using code-generation-time schema mapping ([as documented here](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/schema-mapping/)), redirecting both schemas `myschema` and `otherschema` to the same target schema `dest`. If you do that, and there is a single object (e.g. a table) that appears in both schemas, you will get this ambiguity where jOOQ doesn't know what to do with the duplicate class name.

As far as the DB2 aliases are concerned, they are not supported yet as of jOOQ 3.8 (see https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5564)